# Code doesn't work? I can't move left or right

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am following a tutorial from Zenva and it seems that my code isn't working, it should in theory move left right and jump.

```
extends KinematicBody2D
var score : int =  0
var speed : int = 200
var jumpForce : int = 600
var gravity : int = 800
var vel : Vector2 = Vector2()
onready var sprite : Sprite = get_node("Sprite")
    func _physics_process(delta):
     vel.x = 0
     #move
     if Input.is_action_pressed("leftMove"):
            vel.x -= speed
     if Input.is_action_pressed("rightMove"):
        vel.x += speed
     vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector2.UP)
    
     #flipWhileDirection
     if vel.x < 0:
        sprite.flip_h = true
     elif vel.x > 0:
        sprite.flip_h = false   
    
    
     #gravity
     vel.y += gravity * delta
    
     if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        vel.y -= jumpForce
```

Now here is the input map.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far to debug your code?

Comment: I'm going to venture to guess you didn't add any floor for the player character to stand on. *I would organize the code differently, but that is a different tale.* Edit: by the way, "isn't working" is not a great way to describe a problem.

Comment: @Theraot I don't know how relevant it is, but the title says "can't move left or right".

Comment: @Vaillancourt True. Well, my guess is that it does move left and right, but it is either hard to see (the player character falls off-screen too fast) or impossible to see (there is a camera attached to the player character, keeping it centered on the screen, and there is no environment). Either way it needs a floor. Of course, that is just a guess, if I'm wrong, I would have to wait for OP to elaborate.

Comment: I cannot see it fall of the screen in my Godot Editor, I tried removing the jump function but didn't work(I did put it back) I thought it was some error where the value was returning void, so I rewrote some if conditions. But none seemed to work.

Comment: Update: I added a floor/tile according to the tutorial, but it still doesn't function properly.